# C++ How to get value from this string

Tags: c++, html-parsing

How do i get the value in this chunk of html code

```html
<select id="convert-from" name="currency-1">
  <option value='EUR'>Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option value='GBP'>British Pound (GBP)</option>
  <option value='USD'>United States Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option value='AUD'>Australian Dollar (AUD)</option>
  <option value='CAD'>Canadian Dollar (CAD)</option>
  <option value='CHF'>Swiss Franc (CHF)</option>
  <option value='CNY'>Chinese Yuan (CNY)</option>
</select>
```

I want the value e.g EURO (EUR), Brish Pound (GBP) and output it into a file called currency.txt in this format:

> EURO (EUR)
>   British Pound (GBP)
>   United States Dollar (USD)
>   Australian Dollar (AUD)

Comment: Just google for `C++ HTML parser` and you will get lots of useful results. Also have a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser).

Comment: If its for a one of, a simple sed/awk script will do. If you'll have to do it regularly, then use and XML/HTML parser

Comment: I will use libxml to parse it

Answer (score 3):

Use an XML/HTML parser (I'm not going to recommend any specific ones, but there are plenty). A less general approach would be to try to parse this yourself, *e.g.* using regular expressions.

Comment: You haven't been around too long, so you're forgiven for suggesting to  'parse' HTML using regular expression despite of the answer given about this at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/91757 ;-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I didn't suggest parsing general HTML using regular expressions, just the pseudo-format that the OP presented. I pointed this out ("less general" *vide supra*)